# Gradient registry has no entry for a tensorflow custom op

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

Recently I made a tensorflow custom op used to crop and resize 3D features. I have finished the coding of forward and backward, and successfully compiled it. However, when I used this op in a layer, an error came up telling that gradient registry has no entry for my forward op, and no gradient defined for it. Here are the details:

This is the .cc file

```
#include <cstring>
#include "third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/shape_inference.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"
#include "crop_and_resize_op.h"
#include "cuda.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/register_types.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/types.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/util/work_sharder.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/util/tensor_format.h"

namespace tensorflow {
using ::tensorflow::shape_inference::DimensionHandle;
using ::tensorflow::shape_inference::ShapeHandle;
using ::tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext;

Status SetOutputToSizedImage(::tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext* c, ::tensorflow::shape_inference::DimensionHandle batch_dim,
                             int size_input_idx, ::tensorflow::shape_inference::DimensionHandle channel_dim) {
  // Verify shape of size input.
  ShapeHandle size;
  TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(c->WithRank(c->input(size_input_idx), 1, &size));
  DimensionHandle unused;
  TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(c->WithValue(c->Dim(size, 0), 3, &unused));

  // Get size values from the size tensor.
  const Tensor* size_tensor = c->input_tensor(size_input_idx);
  DimensionHandle width;
  DimensionHandle height;
  DimensionHandle depth;
  if (size_tensor == nullptr) {
    width = c->UnknownDim();
    height = c->UnknownDim();
    depth = c->UnknownDim();
  } else {
    // TODO(petewarden) - Remove once we have constant evaluation in C++ only.
    if (size_tensor->dtype() != DT_INT32) {
      return errors::InvalidArgument(
          "Bad size input type for SetOutputToSizedImage: Expected DT_INT32 "
          "but got ",
          DataTypeString(size_tensor->dtype()), " for input #", size_input_idx,
          " in ", c->DebugString());
    }
    auto vec = size_tensor->vec<int32>();
    height = c->MakeDim(vec(0));
    width = c->MakeDim(vec(1));
    depth = c->MakeDim(vec(2));
  }
  c->set_output(0, c->MakeShape({batch_dim, height, width, depth, channel_dim}));
  return Status::OK();
}

REGISTER_OP("CropResize")
    .Input("image: T")
    .Input("boxes: float")
    .Input("box_ind: int32")
    .Input("crop_size: int32")
    .Output("crops: float")
    .Attr("T: {uint8, uint16, int8, int16, int32, int64, half, float, double}")
    .Attr("method: {'bilinear'} = 'bilinear'")
    .Attr("extrapolation_value: float = 0")
    .SetShapeFn([](::tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext* c) {
    // Get inputs and validate ranks.
        ShapeHandle input;
        TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(c->WithRank(c->input(0), 5, &input));
        ShapeHandle boxes;
        TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(c->WithRank(c->input(1), 2, &boxes));
        ShapeHandle box_ind;
        TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(c->WithRank(c->input(2), 1, &box_ind));

    // boxes[0] and box_ind[0] are both num_boxes.
        DimensionHandle num_boxes_dim;
        TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(
            c->Merge(c->Dim(boxes, 0), c->Dim(box_ind, 0), &num_boxes_dim));

    // boxes.dim(1) is 4.
        DimensionHandle unused;
        TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(c->WithValue(c->Dim(boxes, 1), 6, &unused));

        return SetOutputToSizedImage(c, num_boxes_dim, 3 /* size_input_idx */,
            c->Dim(input, 4));
});

REGISTER_OP("CropResizeGradImage")
    .Input("grads: float")
    .Input("boxes: float")
    .Input("box_ind: int32")
    .Input("image_size: int32")
    .Output("output: T")
    .Attr("T: {float, half, double}")
    .Attr("method: {'bilinear'} = 'bilinear'")
    .SetShapeFn([](::tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext* c) {
        ShapeHandle out;
        TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(c->MakeShapeFromShapeTensor(3, &out));
        TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(c->WithRank(out, 5, &out));
        c->set_output(0, out);
        return Status::OK();
    });
//
REGISTER_OP("CropResizeGradBoxes")
    .Input("grads: float")
    .Input("image: T")
    .Input("boxes: float")
    .Input("box_ind: int32")
    .Output("output: float")
    .Attr("T: {uint8, uint16, int8, int16, int32, int64, half, float, double}")
    .Attr("method: {'bilinear'} = 'bilinear'")
    .SetShapeFn([](::tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext* c) {
        c->set_output(0, c->input(2));
        return Status::OK();
    });
}
namespace tensorflow 
{
    using CPUDevice = Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice;
    using GPUDevice = Eigen::GpuDevice;
    namespace {

        static inline Status ParseAndCheckBoxSizes(const Tensor& boxes, const Tensor& box_index, int* num_boxes)
        {
            if (boxes.NumElements() == 0 && box_index.NumElements() == 0) {
                *num_boxes = 0;
                return Status::OK();
            }
            // The shape of 'boxes' is [num_boxes, 6].
            if (boxes.dims() != 2) {
                return errors::InvalidArgument("boxes must be 2-D",
                    boxes.shape().DebugString());
            }
            *num_boxes = boxes.dim_size(0);
            if (boxes.dim_size(1) != 6) {
                return errors::InvalidArgument("boxes must have 6 columns");
            }
            // The shape of 'box_index' is [num_boxes].
            if (box_index.dims() != 1) {
                return errors::InvalidArgument("box_index must be 1-D",
                    box_index.shape().DebugString());
            }
            if (box_index.dim_size(0) != *num_boxes) {
                return errors::InvalidArgument("box_index has incompatible shape");
            }
            return Status::OK();
        }

    }
    template <typename Device, typename T>
    class CropResizeOp : public OpKernel {
    public:
        explicit CropResizeOp(OpKernelConstruction* context)
            : OpKernel(context) {
            string method;
            OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->GetAttr("method", &method));
            OP_REQUIRES(context, method == "bilinear",
                errors::InvalidArgument("method must be 'bilinear'", method));
            OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->GetAttr("extrapolation_value",
                &extrapolation_value_));
        }

        void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
            // The shape of 'image' is [batch_size, image_height, image_width, image_depth,
            // channels].
            const Tensor& image = context->input(0);
            // The shape of 'boxes' is [num_boxes, 6].
            const Tensor& boxes = context->input(1);
            // The shape of 'box_index' is [num_boxes].
            const Tensor& box_index = context->input(2);
            // The shape of 'crop_size' is [3].
            const Tensor& crop_size = context->input(3);

            // Validate inputs dimensions.
            OP_REQUIRES(context, image.dims() == 5,
                errors::InvalidArgument("input image must be 5-D",
                    image.shape().DebugString()));
            const int batch_size = image.dim_size(0);
            const int image_height = image.dim_size(1);
            const int image_width = image.dim_size(2);
            const int image_depth = image.dim_size(3);
            const int depth = image.dim_size(4);
            OP_REQUIRES(
                context, image_height > 0 && image_width > 0,
                errors::InvalidArgument("image dimensions must be positive"));
            int num_boxes = 0;
            OP_REQUIRES_OK(
                context, ParseAndCheckBoxSizes(boxes, box_index, &num_boxes));

            OP_REQUIRES(context, crop_size.dims() == 1,
                errors::InvalidArgument("crop_size must be 1-D",
                    crop_size.shape().DebugString()));
            OP_REQUIRES(
                context, crop_size.dim_size(0) == 3,
                errors::InvalidArgument("crop_size must have three elements",
                    crop_size.shape().DebugString()));

            // Copy and validate crop sizes.
            auto crop_size_vec = crop_size.vec<int32>();
//          const int crop_height = ::tensorflow::internal::SubtleMustCopy(crop_size_vec(0));
//          const int crop_width = ::tensorflow::internal::SubtleMustCopy(crop_size_vec(1));
            const int crop_height = crop_size_vec(0);
            const int crop_width = crop_size_vec(1);
            const int crop_depth = crop_size_vec(2);
            OP_REQUIRES(
                context, crop_height > 0 && crop_width > 0 && crop_depth > 0,
                errors::InvalidArgument("crop dimensions must be positive"));

            // Allocate output tensor.
            Tensor* output = nullptr;
            OP_REQUIRES_OK(
                context,
                context->allocate_output(
                    0, TensorShape({ num_boxes, crop_height, crop_width, crop_depth, depth }),
                    &output));


//          const Tensor& image = context->input(0);
//          const Tensor& boxes = context->input(1);
//          const Tensor& box_index = context->input(2);
            const bool status = functor::CropResize<Device, T>()(
                    context, image.tensor<T,5>(), boxes.tensor<float, 2>(),
                    box_index.tensor<int32, 1>(), extrapolation_value_,
                    output->tensor<float,5>());
            if (!status) {
                context->SetStatus(
                        errors::Internal("Failed launch CropAndResizeKernel."));
                }
        }

    private:
        float extrapolation_value_;
    };
    namespace functor {
        template <typename T>
        struct CropResize<CPUDevice, T> {
            bool operator()(const OpKernelContext* context,
                typename TTypes<T,5>::ConstTensor image,
                typename TTypes<float, 2>::ConstTensor boxes,
                typename TTypes<int32, 1>::ConstTensor box_index,
                float extrapolation_value,
                typename TTypes<float,5>::Tensor crops) {
                const int batch_size = image.dimension(0);
                const int image_height = image.dimension(1);
                const int image_width = image.dimension(2);
                const int image_depth = image.dimension(3);
                const int num_boxes = crops.dimension(0);
                const int crop_height = crops.dimension(1);
                const int crop_width = crops.dimension(2);
                const int crop_depth = crops.dimension(3);
                const int depth = crops.dimension(4);

                //operations
                return true;
            }
        };

    }  // namespace functor

    template <typename Device, typename T>
    class CropResizeGradImageOp : public OpKernel {
    public:
        explicit CropResizeGradImageOp(OpKernelConstruction* context)
            : OpKernel(context) {
            string method;
            OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->GetAttr("method", &method));
            OP_REQUIRES(context, method == "bilinear",
                errors::InvalidArgument("method must be 'bilinear'", method));
        }

        void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
            // The shape of 'grads' is [num_boxes, crop_height, crop_width, crop_depth, depth].
            const Tensor& grads = context->input(0);
            // The shape of 'boxes' is [num_boxes, 6].
            const Tensor& boxes = context->input(1);
            // The shape of 'box_index' is [num_boxes].
            const Tensor& box_index = context->input(2);
            // The shape of 'image_size' is [5].
            const Tensor& image_size = context->input(3);

            // Validate input shapes.
            OP_REQUIRES(context, grads.dims() == 5,
                errors::InvalidArgument("grads image must be 5-D",
                    grads.shape().DebugString()));
            const int crop_height = grads.dim_size(1);
            const int crop_width = grads.dim_size(2);
            const int crop_depth = grads.dim_size(3);
            OP_REQUIRES(
                context, crop_height > 0 && crop_width > 0,
                errors::InvalidArgument("grads dimensions must be positive"));
            int num_boxes = 0;
            OP_REQUIRES_OK(
                context, ParseAndCheckBoxSizes(boxes, box_index, &num_boxes));
            OP_REQUIRES(
                context, grads.dim_size(0) == num_boxes,
                errors::InvalidArgument("boxes and grads have incompatible shape"));

            OP_REQUIRES(context, image_size.dims() == 1,
                errors::InvalidArgument("image_size must be 1-D",
                    image_size.shape().DebugString()));
            OP_REQUIRES(context, image_size.dim_size(0) == 5,
                errors::InvalidArgument("image_size must have 5 elements",
                    image_size.shape().DebugString()));
            auto image_size_vec = image_size.vec<int32>();
//          const int batch_size = ::tensorflow::internal::SubtleMustCopy(image_size_vec(0));
//          const int image_height = ::tensorflow::internal::SubtleMustCopy(image_size_vec(1));
//          const int image_width = ::tensorflow::internal::SubtleMustCopy(image_size_vec(2));
//          const int depth = ::tensorflow::internal::SubtleMustCopy(image_size_vec(3));
            const int batch_size = image_size_vec(0);
            const int image_height = image_size_vec(1);
            const int image_width = image_size_vec(2);
            const int image_depth = image_size_vec(3);
            const int depth = image_size_vec(4);

            OP_REQUIRES(
                context, image_height > 0 && image_width > 0,
                errors::InvalidArgument("image dimensions must be positive"));
            OP_REQUIRES(
                context, grads.dim_size(4) == depth,
                errors::InvalidArgument("image_size and grads are incompatible"));

            // Allocate output tensor.
            Tensor* output = nullptr;
            OP_REQUIRES_OK(
                context,
                context->allocate_output(
                    0, TensorShape({ batch_size, image_height, image_width, image_depth, depth }),
                    &output));

                const bool status = functor::CropResizeBackpropImage<Device, T>()(
                    context->eigen_device<Device>(), grads.tensor<float, 5>(),
                    boxes.tensor<float, 2>(), box_index.tensor<int32, 1>(),
                    output->tensor<T, 5>());
                if (!status) {
                    context->SetStatus(errors::Internal(
                        "Failed launch CropAndResizeBackpropImage kernel."));
                }

//          RunIfBoxIndexIsValid<Device>(context, box_index.tensor<int32, 1>(),
//              batch_size, std::move(compute_callback),
//              std::move(done));
        }
    };
    namespace functor {
        template <typename T>
        struct CropResizeBackpropImage<CPUDevice, T> {
            bool operator()(const CPUDevice& d,
                typename TTypes<float, 5>::ConstTensor grads,
                typename TTypes<float, 2>::ConstTensor boxes,
                typename TTypes<int32, 1>::ConstTensor box_index,
                typename TTypes<T, 5>::Tensor grads_image) {
                const int batch_size = grads_image.dimension(0);
                const int image_height = grads_image.dimension(1);
                const int image_width = grads_image.dimension(2);
                const int image_depth = grads_image.dimension(3);
                const int num_boxes = grads.dimension(0);
                const int crop_height = grads.dimension(1);
                const int crop_width = grads.dimension(2);
                const int crop_depth = grads.dimension(3);
                const int depth = grads.dimension(4);

                grads_image.setZero();

                //operations
        };

    }  // namespace functor

    template <typename Device, typename T>
    class CropResizeGradBoxesOp : public OpKernel {
    public:
        explicit CropResizeGradBoxesOp(OpKernelConstruction* context)
            : OpKernel(context) {
            string method;
            OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->GetAttr("method", &method));
            OP_REQUIRES(context, method == "bilinear",
                errors::InvalidArgument("method must be 'bilinear'", method));
        }

        void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
            // The shape of 'grads' is [num_boxes, crop_height, crop_width, crop_depth, depth].
            const Tensor& grads = context->input(0);
            // The shape of 'boxes' is [num_boxes, 6].
            const Tensor& boxes = context->input(2);
            // The shape of 'box_index' is [num_boxes].
            const Tensor& box_index = context->input(3);
            // The shape of 'image' is [batch_size, image_height, image_width, image_depth, depth].
            const Tensor& image = context->input(1);

            // Validate input shapes.
            OP_REQUIRES(context, grads.dims() == 5,
                errors::InvalidArgument("grads image must be 5-D",
                    grads.shape().DebugString()));
            const int crop_height = grads.dim_size(1);
            const int crop_width = grads.dim_size(2);
            const int crop_depth = grads.dim_size(3);
            const int depth = grads.dim_size(4);
            OP_REQUIRES(
                context, crop_height > 0 && crop_width > 0,
                errors::InvalidArgument("grads dimensions must be positive"));

            OP_REQUIRES(context, image.dims() == 5,
                errors::InvalidArgument("input image must be 5-D",
                    image.shape().DebugString()));
            const int batch_size = image.dim_size(0);
            const int image_height = image.dim_size(1);
            const int image_width = image.dim_size(2);
            OP_REQUIRES(
                context, image_height > 0 && image_width > 0,
                errors::InvalidArgument("image dimensions must be positive"));
            OP_REQUIRES(context, image.dim_size(4) == depth,
                errors::InvalidArgument("image, grads depth differ"));

            int num_boxes = 0;
            OP_REQUIRES_OK(
                context, ParseAndCheckBoxSizes(boxes, box_index, &num_boxes));

            OP_REQUIRES(
                context, grads.dim_size(0) == num_boxes,
                errors::InvalidArgument("boxes and grads have incompatible shape"));

            // Allocate output tensor.
            Tensor* output = nullptr;
            OP_REQUIRES_OK(
                context,
                context->allocate_output(0, TensorShape({ num_boxes, 6 }), &output));



            const bool status = functor::CropResizeBackpropBoxes<Device, T>()(
                    context->eigen_device<Device>(), grads.tensor<float, 5>(),
                    image.tensor<T, 5>(), boxes.tensor<float, 2>(),
                    box_index.tensor<int32, 1>(), output->tensor<float, 2>());
            if (!status) {
                    context->SetStatus(errors::Internal(
                        "Failed launch CropAndResizeBackpropBoxes kernel."));
                }


//          RunIfBoxIndexIsValid<Device>(context, box_index.tensor<int32, 1>(),
//              batch_size, std::move(compute_callback),
//              std::move(done));
        }
    };
//  // Partial specialization of CropAndResizeBackpropBoxes functor for a CPUDevice.
    namespace functor {
        template <typename T>
        struct CropResizeBackpropBoxes<CPUDevice, T> {
            bool operator()(const CPUDevice& d,
                typename TTypes<float, 5>::ConstTensor grads,
                typename TTypes<T, 5>::ConstTensor image,
                typename TTypes<float, 2>::ConstTensor boxes,
                typename TTypes<int32, 1>::ConstTensor box_index,
                typename TTypes<float, 2>::Tensor grads_boxes) {
                const int batch_size = image.dimension(0);
                const int image_height = image.dimension(1);
                const int image_width = image.dimension(2);
                const int image_depth = image.dimension(3);
                const int num_boxes = grads.dimension(0);
                const int crop_height = grads.dimension(1);
                const int crop_width = grads.dimension(2);
                const int crop_depth = grads.dimension(3);
                const int depth = grads.dimension(4);

                grads_boxes.setZero();

                //operations
                return true;
            }
        };

    }  // namespace functor

    #define REGISTER_KERNEL(T)                                \
        REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("CropResize")           \
                              .Device(DEVICE_CPU)         \
                              .TypeConstraint<T>("T")     \
                              .HostMemory("crop_size"),   \
                          CropResizeOp<CPUDevice, T>);      \
        REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("CropResizeGradBoxes")  \
                              .Device(DEVICE_CPU)         \
                              .TypeConstraint<T>("T"),    \
                          CropResizeGradBoxesOp<CPUDevice, T>);
    TF_CALL_float(REGISTER_KERNEL);
        //TF_CALL_double(REGISTER_KERNEL);

        //TF_CALL_REAL_NUMBER_TYPES(REGISTER_KERNEL);

    #undef REGISTER_KERNEL


    #define REGISTER_KERNEL(T)                               \
        REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("CropResizeGradImage") \
                              .Device(DEVICE_CPU)        \
                              .TypeConstraint<T>("T")    \
                              .HostMemory("image_size"), \
                          CropResizeGradImageOp<CPUDevice, T>);

    TF_CALL_float(REGISTER_KERNEL);
    TF_CALL_double(REGISTER_KERNEL);

    #undef REGISTER_KERNEL

    #if GOOGLE_CUDA


        #define REGISTER_KERNEL(T)                                         \
//          extern template CropResizeOp<GPUDevice, T> \
//          extern template CropResizeGradImageOp<GPUDevice, T> \
//          extern template CropResizeGradBoxesOp<GPUDevice, T> \


            REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("CropResize")                    \
                              .Device(DEVICE_GPU)                  \
                              .TypeConstraint<T>("T")              \
                              .HostMemory("crop_size"),            \
                          CropResizeOp<GPUDevice, T>);          \
            REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("CropResizeGradImage")           \
                              .Device(DEVICE_GPU)                  \
                              .TypeConstraint<T>("T")              \
                              .HostMemory("image_size"),           \
                          CropResizeGradImageOp<GPUDevice, T>);                                                      \
            REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("CropResizeGradBoxes")           \
                              .Device(DEVICE_GPU)                  \
                              .TypeConstraint<T>("T"),             \
                          CropResizeGradBoxesOp<GPUDevice, T>);
        TF_CALL_GPU_NUMBER_TYPES(REGISTER_KERNEL);

        #undef REGISTER_KERNEL
        //REGISTER_GPU(float);
        //REGISTER_GPU(int32);
    #endif  // GOOGLE_CUDA

}
```

Here is the test part:

```
box_opt = tf.load_op_library('/home/yankun/tensorflow/CR/crop_and_resize_op_gpu.so')
    idx = box_opt.crop_resize(dets,bboxes, box_idx, [5, 5,5], name='mult')
    mult = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name('mult')
    print(get_gradient_function(mult))
```

This is the part where this op is used in a layer:

```
for j in range(0, boxes_shape[1]):
        box_opt = tf.load_op_library('/home/yankun/tensorflow/CR/crop_and_resize_op_gpu.so')
        pool_image = box_opt.crop_resize(tf.cast(feature_maps, tf.float32), boxes[:,j,:],
                                    box_ids,
                                    [8, 8, 8])
        print(pool_image)
        pooled_total.append(pool_image[0])
```

Here comes the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 605, in _GradientsHelper
    grad_fn = ops.get_gradient_function(op)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2471, in get_gradient_function
    return _gradient_registry.lookup(op_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/registry.py", line 93, in lookup
    "%s registry has no entry for: %s" % (self._name, name))
LookupError: gradient registry has no entry for: CropResize

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generator.py", line 849, in <module>
    Train()
  File "generator.py", line 842, in Train
    callbacks=[checkpoint, history, lrate], initial_epoch=0)
  File "/home/yankun/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yankun/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1415, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/home/yankun/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 39, in fit_generator
    model._make_train_function()
  File "/home/yankun/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 498, in _make_train_function
    loss=self.total_loss)
  File "/home/yankun/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yankun/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 470, in get_updates
    grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
  File "/home/yankun/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 89, in get_gradients
    grads = K.gradients(loss, params)
  File "/home/yankun/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2708, in gradients
    return tf.gradients(loss, variables, colocate_gradients_with_ops=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 494, in gradients
    gate_gradients, aggregation_method, stop_gradients)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 609, in _GradientsHelper
    (op.name, op.type))
LookupError: No gradient defined for operation 'pyramid_roi_align_1/CropResize' (op type: CropResize)
```

So my question is, is this error caused by my .cc file or did I miss something in the .py file. And how to define the gradients for a custom op?
Thank you!

Comment: Too much code. Can you trim this down to a [mcve] please?

Answer (score 2):

You should register gradient with python like this:

```
@ops.RegisterGradient("OpName")
def _OpNameGrad(op, grad):
    # define your gradient here
```

In your c++ code, you define 2 op, and in this python code, set how one op is another's gradient.

For more detail, see https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op#implement_the_gradient_in_python

For more examples, see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/math_grad.py

Comment: Thank you so much, I added the registration and the problem solved!